# Use VisualStudio 2010 for editing InfoPath C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, infopath, infopath-2007, vsta

The default editor for InfoPath 2007 C# code is VSTA. It has very low functionality and I want to use my VS 2010. Is this possible? If yes, how?

I tried to create a project out of an existing one, but i couldnt import the correct assemblies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Visual Studio 2010 does not include the InfoPath form template projects that were provided in previous versions of Visual Studio. You also cannot use Visual Studio 2010 to open or edit an InfoPath form template project that was created in a previous version of Visual Studio."

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/officedevelopmentprerelease/thread/18a93486-0773-44cb-ae04-cc4b8f75c205

How to do development with Infopath and Visual Studio 2010 Video :
http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/Office2010/InfoPathUnit/InfoPathVisualStudio

Comment: This video does not talk about VS 2010... just InfoPath 2010... and I think that the IDE being used in the background is VS 2005 with VSTA. Maybe an edit is needed.
That's what your first paragraph says, but the text before the second link is unclear.